# Get an Access Token from an Identity Provider in .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, access-token, openid-connect, idp

I am setting up OAuth 2 and OIDC at my company.

I used [oidc-client.js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) to handle getting the access token for calls to API's protected by OAuth 2 and OIDC from a javascript client.

I now need to get an access token when the client is a C# .NET Core application calling an API that is protected by OAuth 2 and OIDC.

I could try to code this up myself.  But there is a lot to it and I worry I will get some of it wrong.  Hence this question:

**Does .NET Core include libraries to get a Access Token from an Identity Provider?**

**To be clear**, I am **NOT** looking for the code to protect an ASP.NET service with OAuth2 and OIDC.  That code is very common and easily found.  (So easy in fact that find what I am looking for is hard.)

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Identity Model OIDC Client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient) in .Net Core projects that make outgoing requests. It supports all the main flows I believe and is certified / standards based.

Some code of mine that uses its classes [here](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/OAuthAuthenticator.cs) to demonstrate the type of syntax.

If you are writing a non browser app that logs a user in, then that is tricky and tends to involve invoking the system browser. The above library has [classes to support that](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/token.html).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes there is. If I understand your question.

Check out the docs on IdentityServer4 https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ as it gives examples of accessing an OAuth2 token service from asp.net core and it should translate to whatever token server you are using.

But essentially you setup the http client you are going to use for your request:
Where: Client is an instance of an HttpClient

```
DiscoveryDocumentResponse disco = await 
Client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://your_token_server/");

var tokenResponse = await Client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new 
ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
        {
            Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,

            ClientId = "Some_Client_Id",
            ClientSecret = "Some_Client_Secret",
            Scope = "Some_Api_Scope"
        });
        Client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
```

The api will also need to be setup but there are lots of examples on the docs I suggested